# Is a TU matrix appended with smaller identity matrices still TU?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, total-unimodularity, unimodular-matrices

Let $A$ be a TU matrix of consecutive ones, and $I$ be an identity matrix.
We know a TU matrix appended to an identity matrix, e.g.,
$$\begin{bmatrix}
& & & | & & & \\
& A & & | & I & &\\
& & & | & & &\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
remains to be TU.

Then, can I further append smaller identity matrices, e.g.,
$$\begin{bmatrix}
& & & | & & & | I\\
& A & & | & I & & | I\\
& & & | & & & | I\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and keep TU structure?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the consecutive-ones matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&0
\end{pmatrix};$$
from the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
A&\Biggm|&I_4&\Biggm|&\begin{matrix}I_2\\I_2\end{matrix}
\end{pmatrix}$$
we take the first two and  last two columns to obtain the submatrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&1
\end{pmatrix},$$
which has determinant $-2$.